# Execute a PL/SQL procedure using Java code

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, plsql

I would like to execute PL/SQL procedure using Java code. I've tried this so far :

```
Statement myStmt = null;

myStmt = conn.createStatement();
myStmt.executeQuery("EXECUTE ProjetIRSTEA.detectionX");
```

And I get the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
myStmt.executeUpdate("BEGIN ProjetIRSTEA.detectionX; END");
```

You can also use a method of calling stored procedures defined by the JDBC standard, using CallableStatement Interface:

```
CallableStatement myCall = connection.prepareCall("{call ProjetIRSTEA.detectionX()}")
myCall.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the CallableStatement class to execute Stored Procedures.

Please, check this sample published by Oracle to see how to use this class:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/java.816/a81354/samapp2.htm

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle, you can use either a CallableStatement (as explained above) or just issue a normal sql query using a Statement or PreparedStatement (the former method is preferred though) .

```
String sql = " select ProjetIRSTEA.detectionX() from dual";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.execute();
```

Note that you  have to reference the system table dual in your select statement.

Comment: Note that this only works if `ProjetIRSTEA.detectionX` is a function. Procedures cannot be invoked from a SELECT statement.